# UICollectionView not linking to my datasource swift

Tags: swift, debugging, uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue

So I have 2 controllers. The login page called `viewController` and the dashboard called `SecondViewController`. For now you click the login page and go to the second view controller where it creates a `CollectionView`.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccessful", sender:  self)
```

That's my segue to go to the `SecondViewController`. So now for the `SecondViewController` I created a `UICollectionView` and I created custom cells on the `storyboard` and connected the `CollectionView` to the data source. Now when my login goes to my `SecondViewController` it show me below error.

```
SecondViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector
```

**Here is my SecondViewController Code:**

```
import UIKit


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var UiToolbar: UINavigationItem!

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }


}
```

The `PhotoCell` is the identifier for my `collectionViewCells`. I appreciate anybody who can help me out.

Comment: You need to change you extension class from `ViewController` to `SecondViewController` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did the simple mistake just change extension to Second View Controller. like

```
extension SecondViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }


}
```